# Angular $resource returns TypeError

Tags: angularjs, resources

Hello I am trying to get a url from my api using the ngResource and I have a service that returns the resource. However when I call it inside my controller is gives me an error of Cannot read property 'query' of undefined.

Why is this happening?

This is my service :

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.service('ContactResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {

      return $resource('/contacts/:firstname', {firstname: '@firstname'},
        {
          'update': {method: 'PUT'}
        }
      );
  }]);

}());
```

This is my controller

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.controller('contactsCtrl', ['ContactResource', function($scope, Contacts, ContactResource) {
    $scope.contacts = ContactResource.query();
  }]);

}());
```

And this is my HTML

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>Firstname <input type="search" class="pull-right"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <td>
        <a ng-href="/{{ contact.firstname }}">{{ contact.firstname }}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
['ContactResource', function($scope, Contacts, ContactResource)
```

You need to also inject `$scope` and `Contacts` into the array, like this:

```
['$scope', 'Contacts', 'ContactResource', function($scope, Contacts, ContactResource)
```

Or Angular will think that `'ContactResource'` is the same as `$scope`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved it. Great explanation.